# Pyspark SparkSQL regex to get substring before space

Tags: java, regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I have written an SQL in Athena, that uses the regex_extract to extract substring from a column, it extracts string, where there is "X10003" and takes up to when the space appears. for example from `5570 - Site 811111 - X10003-10447-XXX-20443 (CAMP)` it extracts `X10003-10447-XXX-20443` and it works fine using `REGEXP_EXTRACT(site, 'X10033.*?\w+-\d+')` in Athena.

Now I am converting this to sparkSQL and it does not work properly, I have applied different ways but nothing works, for example I have used expression:
`Regexp_extract("5570 - Site 811111 - X10003-10447-XXX-20443 (CAMP)", 'X10003([^\s]+)')` gives me `-10447-XXX-20443 (CAMP)` which is not what I require.

Can anyone tells me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(site, '(X10003.*?[A-Za-z0-9]-[0-9]+)', 1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5nHMw/1).

The `(X10003.*?[A-Za-z0-9]-[0-9]+)` pattern is a *capturing group* with ID 1 that matches

- `X10003` - a literal string
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` - an alphanumeric char
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits.

Comment: It worked :) will it work with RLIKE as well?

Comment: @shzyincu It should work with RLIKE as well. I think you won't even need the parentheses, they are only used to tell `REGEXP_EXTRACT` what we want to extract. In RLIKE, it does not extract anything, the regex is only used to test for  a match there.

Answer (score 0):

Enlarge the capture group:

```
Regexp_extract("5570 - Site 811111 - X10003-10447-XXX-20443 (CAMP)", '(X10003[^\s]+)')
#                                                             here ___^
```

Comment: Its giving X10003-10447-XXX-20443 (CAMP) as the response, not what i want

Comment: @shzyincu: Really? it shouldn't, it should stop before the first space.